# My col div seems to increase in size when i reduce my browser width

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html, layout

Im having a problem with a current col that I have. The size increases whenever i get to a certain point of minimizing the width of the browser screen. I dont mind setting a fixed size however last time I changed to fixed; the text on the right merged with the profile box.

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image: After]

**At the the beginning col-md-4 is the grey container of the profile picture and info.**

```html
<div class="container3" style="padding-top:50px;min-width: 1100px;" >
<div id="">
 <div class="row" style="" >

<div class="" style="">
  <div class="col-md-4"  style="background-color:#DDDDDD;height:100%;border-radius: 4px;">
   <!-- Make an if statement for online and offline -->

  <div class="row center">
<% if @user.online? %>
<div class="btn btn-block" id="available">
    Online Now
   </div>
   <% else %>
   <div class="btn btn-block" id="unavailable" style="background-color:#990000;">
    Offline
   </div>
   <% end %>

   <div id="contain-pic">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="width:300px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;background-color:black;">
     <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium), :id => "image-tag", class: "portrait" %>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="average_rating"></div>
    <script>
 $('#average_rating').raty({
  path: '/assets',
  readOnly: true,
  score: <%= @user.reviews.average(:star) %>
 });
</script>

   </div>

   <div class="row " style="margin-left:20px;">
   
    <div class="row" >
     <div class="col-md-3" >
      <h2 style="font-size:20px;margin:0 auto;">Country:</h2>
     </div>
     <% if @user.country != nil %>
     <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-left:30px;">
      <h><%= @user.country %></h>
     </div>
     <% else %>
     <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-left:30px;height:20px;line-height:25px;">
      <h>N/A</h>
     </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
    

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <h2 style="font-size:20px;margin:0 auto;">University:</h2>
     </div>
     <% if @user.school != nil %>
     <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-left:30px;">
      <h><%= @user.school %></h>
     </div>
     <% else %>
     <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-left:30px;height:20px;line-height:25px;">
      <h>N/A</h>
     </div>
     
    <% end %>
    </div>
    
<% if @user.major != nil %>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <h2 style="font-size:20px;margin:0 auto;">Major:</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-left:30px;height:20px;line-height:25px;">
      <h><%= @user.major %></h>
     </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
<% if @user.occupation != nil %>
    <div class="row" >
     <div class="col-md-3" >
      <h2 style="font-size:20px;margin:0 auto;margin-right:10px;">Occupation:</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-left:30px;height:20px;line-height:25px;">
      <h style=""><%= @user.occupation %></h>
     </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
<% if @user.company_name != nil %>
    <div class="row" >
     <div class="col-md-3" >
      <h2 style="font-size:20px;margin:0 auto;">Company:</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-left:30px;height:20px;line-height:25px;">
      <h><%= @user.company_name %></h>
     </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>

   </div>


  </div>

</div>

  <div class="col-md-8">

   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
     <h2 style="font-size:40px;"> <%= @user.username %></h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="msg-btn">
      <%= link_to 'Send message', new_message_path(to: @user.id), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
     </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row col-md-10" style="height:150px;max-height:300px;margin-left:75px;margin-top:20px;">
    <label style="font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;">About Me</label>
     <div class="description" style="overflow:auto;height:130px;max-height:130px;">
     <% if @user.description != nil %>
      <%= @user.description %>
      <% else %>
      <p> There is no description...... </p>
      <% end %>
     </div>
    </div>

   </div>


   <div class="row col-md-12" style="height:230px;max-height:270px;margin-top:15px;" id="introduction">

    <div class="col-md-6">
     <% if @user.school_description != nil %>
     <h3> School Experience </h3>

     <p><%= @user.school_description %></p>
     <% else %>

     <% end %>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
     <% if @user.occupation_details != nil %>
     <h3> Job Experience </h3>

     <p><%= @user.occupation_details %></p>
     <% else %>

     <% end %>
    </div>
   </div>

<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row center">
<h2 >I am available to revise these types of papers</h2>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <% @user.revisers.each do |reviser| %>
  <%= link_to reviser do %>
  <div class="col-sm-6">

  <div style="border: 3px solid grey;width:300px;max-width:300px;height:165px;max-height:165px;margin:10px;">

    <div>
    <div class="row">
     <h2 style="color:black;" class="center"><%= reviser.try(:essay_type) %></h2>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
     <%= render 'shared/essayicons', reviser: reviser %>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
      
     </div>
     </div>
     
    </div>


  </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:40px;">
 <h4>Reviews</h4>
 <% @revisers.each do |reviser| %>
 <% if !reviser.reviews.blank? %>

  <% reviser.reviews.each do |review| %>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
   <%= image_tag review.user.avatar.url(:medium), :id => "image-tag", class: "img-circle thumbnail2" %><br>
   <%= review.user.username %> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-10">
    <%= link_to reviser.essay_type, reviser %><br>
    <%= review.comment %><br>
    <%= review.created_at.strftime("%v") %>
   </div>
  </div>
  <% end %> 
 <% end %>
 <% end %>
</div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>




</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Bootstrap styling, eg. `class="col-md-8", which is what is telling your columns to resize when you get to a particular window width.

If you head here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options, you can see at what screen size the columns 'break' and re-size. You can adjust those column grid numbers (eg. from `class="col-md-8" to`class="col-md-6") as needed.

It also sounds like you may have an issue with incorrectly nested div tags if they are overlapping as you don't want.

Comment: Your reference helped alot!! it was cause i needed to change my columns to col-sm-* and col-xs-* !! So that fixed all my problems and one div position change!! thanks!!